# How to refresh the parent page while opening the overlay-dialog as child window in jquery

Tags: jquery

parent page:1.jsp

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language='Javascript'>    
            function openOverlayDialog(url, label, width, height) 
            {
             $('#dialogIFrame').attr('src', url);
                $('#overlay-dialog').dialog(
                 {
                   enter code here autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    title: label,
                    close: function () {
                        $('#dialogIFrame').attr('src', '');
                    }
                });
                $('#overlay-dialog').dialog("open");
            }
      function refreshSubmit()
        {
          document.refreshForm.submit();
        }
  function submitAddForm()
      {
        openOverlayDialog('2.jsp', 'addserver', '500', '260');
      }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
<input type="hidden" name="server" value="machinename">
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="javascript:submitAddForm()" >
     <form name="refreshForm" action="servers.do"></form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Child page: 2.jsp

```
  <html>
    <head>
       <script language="JavaScript">
            function refreshParent()
              {
             parent.refreshSubmit();
              }
            </script>
          </head>
          <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000" onload="javascript:refreshParent()" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am opening the overlay dialog(child window) by calling openOverlayDialog function as shown in 1.jsp.In html body of the child page(2.jsp), I had written  onload=refreshParent() for refreshing the parent page.But the problem is child window(overlay dialog) is getting closed when it is refreshing the parent page.Can anyone please suggest, how to refresh parent page without closing overlay dialog(child window) in jquery?